# QPixmap Line Being Skipped

Tags: python, pyqt4, qpixmap

I have the following piece of code:

```
def run(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", ".inp")
        if filename == "":
            pass
        elif filename != "":
            nfile = open(filename, 'w')
            self.pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap('yellow.jpg')
            self.canvas1.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
            self.cursor.movePosition(self.cursor.Start, self.cursor.MoveAnchor)
            self.cursor.movePosition(self.cursor.End, self.cursor.KeepAnchor)
            text = self.cursor.selection()
            text1 = text.toPlainText()
            nfile.write(text1)
            nfile.close()
            fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(filename)
            name = fileInfo.baseName()

            import os
            os.system("rungms {}.inp 13-64 {} {} {}.out".format(name, self.cores_val, self.clusters_val, name))

            from itertools import islice
            import sys

            with open("{}.out".format(name)) as searchfile:
                for line in searchfile:
                    if 'TERMINATED NORMALLY' in line:
                        self.pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap('green.jpg')
                        self.canvas1.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
                    elif 'job aborted' in line:
                        self.pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap('red.jpg')
                        self.canvas1.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
                    else:
                        pass
        else:
            pass
```

My problem is that the two lines involving `QPixmap('yellow.jpg')` are not being read after saving my file. However, if I move these two lines in between the first and second lines of the code (i.e. before filename = QtGui...), then they do work.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: How do you know, they are not being read?
Have you verified that `filename` is not empty? 
As a sidenote: You don't need `elif filename != "": ... else: pass`, since the elif path is always True if `filename == ""` is False.

Comment: Thank you, x squared. I know they are not being read because the image is not being inserted into self.canvas1, whereas in the other instances of these lines further down the code, the images (green and red) are being inserted when I run the program. In addition, my yellow image does changes when I write its correspoinding lines before filename... and after def run(self): I hope this makes sense.